# Cost impact of S3 bucket versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services

What would be the cost impact of enabling bucket versioning, is this feature really needed if we need to avoid additional costs?

As AWS suggests, We recommend that you enable Bucket Versioning to help protect against unintentionally overwriting or deleting objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do You Really Need Versioning**

Versioning refers to maintaining multiple variants of an object in the same Amazon S3 bucket. It is used for the preservation, retrieving, and restoration of every version of each object that is stored in the S3 bucket. Versioning can be used to recover from unintended user actions and application failure easily. An S3 bucket can be used to store multiple objects that have the same key, but they would have different version IDs.

Version-enabled buckets help the user to recover objects in case they have been accidentally deleted or have been overwritten.

- When an object is deleted, instead of removing it permanently, S3
  inserts a    delete marker into it, which becomes the current version
  of that object. The previous versions can always be restored.
- If an object    is overwritten, the object would have new data, which
  is considered as a new version of the object. Even in this case, the
  previous versions of the object can be restored.

**Conclusion**

If your data is more important than the cost then it’s really good to have a version-enabled bucket. Another way is segregating your data based on importance into different buckets and enabling versions on the required one.
Hope you like my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Normal s3 pricing is issued on each version of object. Each version will be consider as an object according to S3. It is recommended that people who are using versioning should put `retention and expiration` on versions.

Reference - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-enhancement-versioning/

Basically it is kind of trade off between `data and cost`.

`Data >>>> cost`

If your data is important and you want to avoid unintentionally overwitting and deletion of object. Use `versioning and MFA` it will really help you. But you will have to pay some extra for each version.

`cost >>>> data`

In this case you can disable above feature.

I will suggest you to `segregate` your buckets based on `use-case and frequency` of access. It will help you to organise your data very well and based on use case you can enable necessary feature on some bucket and can avoid on other buckets.